# Kotlin, DataStore flow values in ViewModel are always null

Tags: kotlin, datastore

Im having trouble understanding why the expiryDate value of the flow from Datastore is always null. checkExpiry() is used to determine a navigation route and is only used in the viewmodel (there are no observers in the active fragment).

Any assistance is appreciated.

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel
@Inject
constructor(
    private val userPreferences: UserPreferences,
    private val savedSate: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val expiryTimestamp = userPreferences.expiryTimestampFlow.asLiveData()

    private fun checkExpiry(): Boolean {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        return (calendar.timeInMillis > expiryTimestamp.value!!)
   }
```

DataStore

```
@Singleton
class UserPreferences
@Inject
constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context) {

    private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("user_preferences")
    private val dataStore = context.dataStore

    //Preferences keys
    private object PreferencesKeys {
        val EXPIRY_TIMESTAMP = longPreferencesKey("expiryTimeStamp")
    }

    //Get Functions
    val expiryTimestampFlow = dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if (exception is IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading expiry date", exception)
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw exception
            }
        }
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.EXPIRY_TIMESTAMP] ?: 1672491600000
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LiveData in your ViewModel is not active. You activate it like this:

```
private val expiryTimestamp = userPreferences.expiryTimestampFlow.asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
```

Edit:

If you call your `checkExpiry()` function when the flow from the DataStore has not emitted a value yet (because it has to do some IO), you can get null in the LiveData.

As you are not observing this value from an activity or fragment, you don't need LiveData. You can query the DataStore like this:

```
private suspend fun checkExpiry(): Boolean {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    return (calendar.timeInMillis > userPreferences.expiryTimestampFlow.first())
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mario, 
I've input the line suggested but get the same 'null' result from expiryTimestamp.value.
Im a little confused by the use of flows. I have used Room and flows previously that dont require a couroutine scope to retrieve data. Why is this case different?

Comment: You were probably observing the Room LiveData from an activity or fragment. That activates the LiveData. For your purpose, I have added a suspend function you can use in the ViewModel that does not need LiveData.

Comment: The suspend function approach worked. Thankyou. Yes, most or all would have had some observer moving lists or objects around, so that makes sense. 

I guess Im now trying to understand, why the suspend function made the difference? It was already being called off the main thread. 

fun navigateToNext() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        if (checkExpiry()) { ...} }

Comment: The suspend function waits for the first emitted value from the flow, before returning a value, as .first() is a suspend function as well. Your original non-suspend function just reads the LiveData value that is present at the time, without waiting / suspending for the first value that is emitted by the flow.